# What is the difference between long and long int in C++

Tags: c++

So I was reading a book about C++ (to be specific [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/111882377X)).
A section of a page from the book:

> The following statement declares the two variables lVariable1 and lVariable2
>   as type long int and sets them equal to the value 1, while dVariable is a >double
>   set to the value 1.0. Notice in the declaration of lVariable2 that the int is
>   assumed and can be left off:

```
// declare two long int variables and set them to 1
long int lVariable1
long lVariable2;
// int is assumed
lVariable1 = lVariable2 = 1;
// declare a variable of type double and set it to 1.0
double dVariable; dVariable = 1.0;
```

says that the "int is asummed and can be left off". What does this mean? Does it mean the variable

```
lVariable1
```

and the variable

```
lVariable2
```

is of the same type (and the same range)?

Also (sorry in advance to my stupidity) but of line 2 of the code above I noticed that it does not have a semicolon. I've tried to do it (copying and pasting the code above into an IDE and compiling it) but it's not valid. I believe that this is just a typo but I'm asking here just to make sure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes.  `long` means `long int`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what it means. Just like "short" and "short int" are the same. It's actually more complicated in that "int long" is also legal and the same.

Comment: I may have seen `int long` in some off-colour ASCII art back in the '80s.